# best way to break long lines having system commands

Tags: perl

What is the best way to break long lines having system commands which are being executed by " ` "

example:

```
my @data = `cat data.txt | perl -ne '/CTX:|ed-as-of time:\\s+(\\w+)\\s+[Feb|Mar|April|May]/ && print' | sed '\$!N;/Sync/P;D'|sed 'N;s/\\n/ /'`;
```

I tried to break it using " `." like below, but am getting errors (sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected:).

```
my @data = `cat data.txt | `.
            `perl -ne '/CTX:|ed-as-of time:\\s+(\\w+)\\s+[Feb|Mar|April|May]/ && print' | sed '\$!N;/Sync/P;D'|sed 'N;s/\\n/ /'`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best ways are to assemble the command in a scalar variable

```
$cmd = "command1 --foo --bar | command2 2>log.err | "
     . " command3 --are-we-done-yet | ...";
@data = `$cmd`;  # or @data = qx($cmd)
```

or to assemble it as an argument to `readpipe`

```
@data = readpipe("command1 --foo --bar | command2 >log.err | "
                 . "command3 --are-we-done-yet | ...");
```